# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'. Getting error in table view

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

Getting following error while selecting and deselecting the row of table.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the
>   layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it
>   has been accessed from the main thread.'

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {return}
        do
        {
            let json = try JSON(data:data)
            let result = json["data"]

            for arr in result.arrayValue{

                self.arrData.append(filterCity (json: arr))

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.filter_Table.reloadData()
                    }
            }


        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }.resume()
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated to the question but it's bad practice to reload the table view in each iteration of the loop. Reload it **once** after the loop.

Comment: put below code outside of for loop.

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.filter_Table.reloadData()
                    }

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen all of your code but you probably shouldn't be accessing the `arrData` from a background thread. Also, only reload the table view once. That should prevent the crash.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    for arr in result.arrayValue {
        self.arrData.append(filterCity (json: arr))
    }
    self.filter_Table.reloadData()
}
```

But this code could be refactored further. First of all, you always append to the array but never create a new one. If you perform your web request twice, your data will be duplicated if you append it to the same array. The solution would be to recreate your array and assign it to when done.

```
let array = result.arrayValue.map { self.filterCity(json: $0) }
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.arrData = array
    self.filter_Table.reloadData()
}
```